# I can get a folder's path but not the sub folders

Tags: android

Can anyone explain why is this not working?

i get my folder's path like this -

```
// getting SDcard root path
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        + "/SecuDrive/");
```

and this is how i replace dots in all the mp3 (audio) file names with "x"

```
@Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        File listFile[] = myDirectory.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {

                } else {
                    String fPath = listFile[i].getPath();

                    for (String ext : TARGET_EXTENSIONS) {
                        fPath = fPath.replace("." + ext,
                                "x" + ext);
                    }

                    listFile[i].renameTo(new File(fPath));
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

for instance-

from ninja.mp3 -> ninjaxmp3

but this is not renaming the files in sub directories. it only renames the files in the parent directory (/SecuDrive/)

Comment: how it'll do so as you're doing nothing with `if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {` condition of sub directory..

Comment: hmmm what should i put after that line?

Comment: see the below answer with vote up..

Comment: i am supposed to just use this line walkdir(listFile[i]); but it gives me error  The method walkdir(File) is undefined for the type Hide.ExplorerDBOperation

Comment: if you can post an answer with this, i will up vote

Answer (score 2):

> Try This

```
public void listFile(String pathname) {
File f = new File(pathname);
File[] listfiles = f.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < listfiles.length; i++) {
    if (listfiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        File[] internalFile = listfiles[i].listFiles();
        for (int j = 0; j < internalFile.length; j++) {
            System.out.println(internalFile[j]);
            if (internalFile[j].isDirectory()) {
                String name = internalFile[j].getAbsolutePath();
                listFile(name);
            }

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(listfiles[i]);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: i want to use asynctask dude and  i want to Rename files!!

Answer (score 0):

1. your code is not efficient in performance. check my code

2.Reason is you are not reading files of Sub directory when you find one. In your code, when you find a directory you need to search through  that directory recursively.

```
    private void getFile(File dir) {

    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir) {
            String name = dir.toString();

            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                getFile(dir); //calling same method inside
                return false;
            }
            else{
                // you get all files here.. try to rename all files here. use variable "name" to do your action like renaming as you said
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

What I would suggest is copy this code in your project and call getFile(), in your doInBackground Method.

UPDATED ANSWER:

```
    private class loaderexample extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
File myDirectory;
    private Context ctx;
    private loader(Context ctx){
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    + "/SecuDrive/");

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        getFile(myDirectory);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

    private void getFile(File dir) {

    File[] listFile = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir) {
            String name = dir.toString();

            if (dir.isDirectory()) {
                getFile(dir); //calling same method inside
                return false;
            }
            else{
                // you get all files here.. try to rename all files here. use variable "name" to do your action like renaming as you said
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}




}
```

Comment: Edited it, check it now

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, all the variables in the method are local variables, and if you want all the file extensions, just remove the if condition and use else(you get all files there). you just have to put getFile(myDirectory); in your doInbcakground method.

Comment: I solved your problem, 10 minutes ago, I have changed code to what you want(for all the files you want). All you need to do is rename all files in else condition in mycode as you just did in your actual code. And call getFile(myDirectory); in doInBackground method. thats it.

Comment: The reason why I don't like your code is it is slower in performance.

Comment: again i am calling it in asynctask. Not in a method. how do i define "Dir"??

Comment: Copy the code into your AsyncTask class, may be just below your onPostexecute or onBindViewHolder methods. Which "Dir" are you talking about? if your talking about "dir" in getFile() method, it is a local variable, Dont bother about it. When you get folder's path into myDirectory variable pass it into getFile(); like this getFile(myDirectory); in onBindViewHolder

Comment: I have updated my answer 5 hours ago.with whole code of asynctask.